# Mimicking WHM backup rotations with S3 Lifecycle

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, whm

I'm setting up a new managed VPS server to back up to Amazon S3. WHM has S3 backup natively implemented now, but it [does not support deletion/rotation](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/amazon-s3-backups-not-deleting.435631/). I'd like to keep a set of backups something like this:

- 2 daily backups in S3
- 1 weekly backup in S3
- 4 weekly backups in Glacier
- 12 monthly backups in Glacier
- yearly backups in Glacier

After WHM backups run, the S3 bucket contains this file structure:

```
       yyyy-mm-dd/
         accountname1.tar.gz
         accountname2.tar.gz
         accountname3.tar.gz
```

I might even want different backup rules for different accounts (some more active, some less so). Given how many WHM accounts are using S3 for backup, surely this is a solved problem? I searched StackOverflow and google, but I'm not finding any info on how to use the S3 LifeCycle to do anything other than "move files older than X."

If this just isn't feasible, feel free to recommend a different WHM backup strategy (though my host's custom offsite backup is prohibitively expensive, so not an option).

Comment: Any expiration policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different folders (S3 path) for your different file types.  Then create a Lifecycle rule on that path.  with the time you want the objects to be in S3, and/or glacier time and expiration

```
/daily/yyyy-mm-dd/    <- no lifecycle rule
     accountname1.tar.gz
     accountname2.tar.gz
     accountname3.tar.gz

/weekly/yyyy-mm-dd/    <- LifeCycleRule "weekly" files older than 7 days 
    are moved to glacier, files older than 45 days are removed from glacier
     accountname1.tar.gz
     accountname2.tar.gz
     accountname3.tar.gz

/monthly/yyyy-mm-dd/    <- LifeCycleRule "monthly" files older than 1 days 
    are moved to glacier, files older than 366 days are removed from glacier
     accountname1.tar.gz
     accountname2.tar.gz
     accountname3.tar.gz
```

Comment: This is a neat idea. Still it seems like an inefficient workaround because i would need 3 different cron jobs for each backup retention frequency. The same backup script would run 3 times in parallel if daily/weekly/monthly are about to be executed. Or am i missing something?

Comment: In addition, having monthly cronjobs gets ugly when restarting the machine that should be backuped.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that WHM backup rotation actually *is* working now with S3 (rumors and documentation to the contrary). This means that greg_diesel's suggestion of using the lifecycle is not necessary to expire old logs (and keep my costs down), but it's the right answer to manage moving older monthly files to glacier before they are deleted by the WHM rotation.

Thanks!